# IF a == true OR b == true statement

Tags: twig

I can't find a way to have TWIG interpret the following conditional statement:

```
{% if a == true or b == true %}
do stuff
{% endif %}
```

Am I missing something or it's not possible?

Comment: And operator: ` {% if  a and b %}
...
{% endif %}

Answer (score 172, accepted):

check this [Twig Reference](https://github.com/vito/chyrp/wiki/Twig-Reference).

You can do it that simple:

```
{% if (a or b) %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The "or" also needs to be lowercase - it seems twig is case sensitive.

Comment: To negate this for multiples:  {%  if not (a or b or c)  %}  ...  {% endif %}

Comment: No need for parentheses.

Answer (score 36):

Comparison expressions should each be in their own brackets:

```
{% if (a == 'foo') or (b == 'bar') %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Alternative if you are inspecting a single variable and a number of possible values:

```
{% if a in ['foo', 'bar', 'qux'] %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: not necessarily, according to Twig's official documentation https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html

Comment: [Correct](https://twigfiddle.com/vwy6vu). I had problems in Drupal 8 and had to wrapping the expressions in brackets solved it.

Comment: @Tim is there a way to abbreviate the following? `{% if (kind == '01') or (kind == '02') or (kind == '03') or (kind == '04') or (kind == '05') %}`

Comment: Use an `in` statement: `{% if kind in ['01', '02'] %} ...`. [Twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/gwktx5).