# twig if one is true and other is false

Tags: twig

In relation to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319011/if-a-true-or-b-true-statement).

What do you do when a == true and b == false? This must be 
Before down voting believe it or not but there's nothing to find on this.

So:

```
{% if a == true and b == false %}
do stuff
{% endif %}
```

You should say that this should work but that isn't:

```
{% if (a == true) and (b == false) %}
do stuff
{% endif %}
```

UPDATE2
This works because one is true and two is false

```
{% if variant.stock.track == true %} 
{% if variant.stock.on_stock == false %}
  ({{ 'Out of stock' | t }}){% else %} ({{ 'In stock' | t }})
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `if a and b == false` or `if a and b is sameas(false)`

Comment: The first one works for me.

Comment: @Luceos: A needs to be true and b needs to be false. So not both. One is true other is false

Comment: That's exactly what my comment said @JaapVermoolen, please note the "or" is not part of the code. (Was holding an icecream while writing the first comment :P)

Comment: @Luceos: Yummy ;) But your testing right now if both are false. A needs to be true and b needs to be false. If so then do stuff...

Comment: `if a` checks for true in both cases, not false

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Normally when verifying for false I use `sameas`. In your case:

```
{% if a and b is sameas(false) %}
```

However [documentation implies](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html) you can also use shorthand if's like this:

```
{% if a and b == false %}
```

Please note that this check depends on the variable being set. If no variable is set, checking for true or false will fail because the variable will have the value `null`.

So if you want to check for true or false and want to be sure that if no value is set you get false; you might use `default`:

```
{% if a and b|default(false) is sameas(false) %}
```

or if you prefer the php-style:

```
{% if a and b|default(false) == false %}
```

This should work as well:

```
{% if variant.stock.track and variant.stock.on_stock|default(false) is sameas(false) %}
      ({{ 'Out of stock' | t }}){% else %} ({{ 'In stock' | t }})
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if variant.stock.track and variant.stock.on_stock|default(false) == false %}
  ({{ 'Out of stock' | t }}){% else %} ({{ 'In stock' | t }})
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm totally confused right now! If you want to test if a == true and b == false then this doesn't work, right?! You always have none or both false/true... See my updated question

Comment: "You always have none or both false/true..." I think you need to clarify your issue, you're not making sense.

Comment: I meant with your code you always have one false and one true. See my updated question. If a must be true and b must be false then do stuff. With your code you can have a true/false and b true/false. So it can go both ways.

Comment: I tested it on a different machine and this works... I'll accept your answer. I don't what's wrong on my side then. Enjoy your icecream ;)

Comment: Maybe your configuration `strict_variables` is set to false in one environment?

Comment: Isn't `same as` instead of `sameas` ?

Comment: Same as used to be an alias for sameas. Seems in 2.x that might no longer be the case.